# Required argument "name" is missing and does not have an android:defaultValue

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation, android-safe-args

I'm having a problem with my code i'm trying to pass arguments between fragments but it gives an exception
 `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Required argument "name" is missing and does not have an android:defaultValue` when run it. Im still still a beginner so i can't really tell where the problem is coming from.

```
class ListNotesFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<FragmentListNotesBinding>(inflater, R.layout.fragment_list_notes, container, false)

        val application = requireNotNull(this.activity).application

        val args = ListNotesFragmentArgs.fromBundle(arguments!!).name

        val dataSource = NoteDatabase.getInstance(application).noteDatabaseDao

        val viewModelFactory = ListNoteViewModelFactory(args, dataSource)

        val listNoteViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, viewModelFactory).get(ListNoteViewModel::class.java)

        binding.listNoteViewModel = listNoteViewModel

        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        binding.addButton.setOnClickListener{
            this.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_listNotesFragment_to_detailNoteFragment)
        }

        listNoteViewModel.navigateToDetailNoteFragment.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer{
            it?.let {
                this.findNavController().navigate(ListNotesFragmentDirections
                    .actionListNotesFragmentToDetailNoteFragment(it.noteId))

                listNoteViewModel.doneNavigating()
            }
        })

        return binding.root
    }

}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So your issue is this row:

```
val args = ListNotesFragmentArgs.fromBundle(arguments!!).name
```

The way to guard yourself from when it's ***null*** is to set a [defaultValue](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#supported_argument_types) in your nav_graph.xml argument so it looks something like this:

```
<argument
    android:name="name"
    app:argType="string"
    app:nullable="true"
    android:defaultValue="@null"/>
```

Comment: For me if I look into crashlytics whi this is coming for only few users and not all?

Comment: Also for me into crashlytics this is coming for one user twice didn't get the exact reason behind this,

Comment: Can you please link your post as what you are refering to might be another situation...